# PHP "time ago" rather than on Oct 4 2013 at 7:50 PM?

Tags: php, time

Many sites like http://facebook.com, http://twitter.com have timestamps but rather than saying the time, it says (x) minutes ago, (x) hours ago, (x) days ago, (x) weeks ago, (x) months ago, etc.

How can you do this in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079421/find-a-file-age-in-php/19079487

Comment: not sure why you want  to do it in PHP. Here's a JQuery plug-in to do it: http://timeago.yarp.com

Answer (score 0):

It's called "fuzzy time" usually, and I generally have rolled my own function depending on the granularity I've needed.  Here's a good place to start:  [Converting PHP Fuzzy time to Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872685/converting-php-fuzzy-time-to-javascript)